# How do I avoid all passphrase prompts for GPG2's asymmetric decryption?

Tags: command-line, gnupg, decryption

I've made my own program which utilizes gpg for encrypting and decrypting (both symmetric and asymmetric). It works fine with gpg1 on all accounts, and it works fine with gpg2 for both kinds of encryption and for symmetric decryption, but I still get a GUI-based passphrase prompt for asymmetric decryption. Any ideas on how to pass it in automatically (without user-input)?

Keep in mind that `--no-use-agent` is obsolete and doesn't do anything in gpg2.

Also keep in mind that I've tried the `--passphrase myPassphrase` and `echo "myPassphrase|gpg --passphrase-fd 0` options (at least the latter of which works fine for symmetric decryption—e.g. for decrypting things encrypted with `-c`).

Also keep in mind that `--batch` and `--yes` don't help.

I'm getting the impression (I don't know this) that GNU Privacy Guard doesn't want to support this sort of thing anymore—which is rather frustrating.

My current workaround idea is to encrypt with gpg2 (to ensure the most secure encryption, if it matters) and decrypt with gpg1—but then I and everyone who uses my program will have to enter their key information into both versions of gpg (I'm not excited about that). Plus, I'm a little worried that they'll stop offering gpg1 one day (I don't know that that will happen, though).

Another alternative is just to allow usage of GPG's GUI-based input box instead of my custom-made one—which I suppose isn't the end of the world.

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04 with GPG 2.2.4 with libcrypt 1.8.1.

Comment: What's wrong with letting an agent deal with the passphrase? It'll probably handle it more securely that your application!

Comment: Also be _very_ cautious of recycling file descriptors... don't use `--passphrase-fd 0`... (_stdin_), use another if you must...

Comment: @Attie Nothing's particularly wrong with it (although it's less predictable since sometimes it asks for a passphrase and sometimes it doesn't; also, it caches passphrases temporarily), but it is nice to customize the look and feel of the passphrase entry (and what it says), and how it responds (and how fast it responds). I'm sure the agent probably is much more secure, as it doesn't require one to trust my program as much (and I now plan to support it). Regarding your second comment—why?

Comment: I know that the task manager can show passwords if you enter them directly with `--passphrase-fd 0`, but putting it in a temporary file (which is immediately deleted after use) and passing it in like `cat "myTempFile"|gpg --passphrase-fd 0 …` gets around that particular issue (as long as a hacking program can't capture the temporary file in that instant). I'm sure there are more issues, though (I just don't know what they all are, if you want to point some out).

Comment: I think you're right that it's best to go with the GUI prompt, after all. It seems to work out a lot better after preliminary tests than when I first attempted it. Hopefully that doesn't change with an update! I'm still a little concerned about cached passphrases, though (even though that's kind of convenient).